# Laravel / JQGrid - Order by on laravel dynamic property

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, jqgrid

I'm currently working with free JQGrid 4.6 version and Laravel 5.8 and I have some issue with a grid that I have develop. So here is the problem recap : i want to sort some columns that contains datas coming from dynamic attributes of my model `Contact`.

Here is the columns of the grid :

```js
{name: "ID_PROJET", hidden:true},
{name: "DT_REEL_DON", align:'center',formatter:'date',sorttype : 'date', datefmt: 'd/m/Y',formatoptions: {srcformat:'Y-m-d',newformat: "d/m/Y"},excel:true, width:90},
{name:"LIBELLE_PROJ", excel:true,width:250},
{name:"contact.full_identite", excel:true},
{name:"MT_DON",formatter:'currency',align:'right',sorttype:'numeric',excel:true, width:60},
{name:"lib_type_don",excel:true, sortable:false},
{name:"lib_moyen_paiement",excel:true,width:60,sortable:false},
{name:"MAIL", excel:true},
{name:"ADRESSE1", excel:true},
{name:"CDPOST", excel:true,width:50},
{name:"COMMUNE", excel:true},
{name:"PAYS", excel:true,width:70},
{name:"SOLLICITE",excel:true,width:30},
{name: "action",template:"action",sortable:false, width: 75, align:"center",excel:false}
```

Datas come from this request that i serialize to JSON :

```php
$dons = $dons->with(['projet','contact'])
     ->join('projet','projet.ID_PROJET',"=",'don.ID_PROJET')
     ->join('contact','contact.ID_CONTACT',"=",'don.ID_CONTACT')
     ->orderBy($sidx,$sord)
     ->select('don.*','contact.MAIL','contact.ADRESSE1','contact.CDPOST','contact.COMMUNE','contact.PAYS','contact.SOLLICITE','projet.LIBELLE_PROJ')
     ->offset($start)->limit($limit)->get();
```

`$sidx`, `$sord`, `$start` and `$limit` are GET parameters send by JQGrid when the user have done an action on the grid (paging, sorting etc)

It's working great, but the problem is for the column `contact.full_identite` which is not a field into my `contacts` table. It's a laravel dynamic attributes define like that :

```php
    public function getFullIdentiteAttribute() {
        // si entreprise 
        if ($this->TYPE_CONTACT_ == 1) {
            return $this->ORGANISME;
        }
        // si particulier
        else if ($this->TYPE_CONTACT_ == 2) {
            return $this->NOM . ' ' . $this->PRENOM;
        }
    }
```

The idea is to return the full name of a person if this is a particular or the organisation name if this a company.
So i'm searching for a way to apply an `orderBy` clause (in my request above) on this dynamic attribute when the user want to sort this column. For the moment, i sort on the field `NOM` and it's working good but this is not the result that i expect.

Here is a screenshot of a structure part of my `contact` table :

[image: Structure table]

Thanks in advance for your help, if i wasn't enough clear don't hesitate to ask me some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, i solved my problem adding conditions on `$sidx` attribute and using Laravel `sortBy`,`sortByDesc` and `splice` methods.

Not sure that is the best way to implement that, but this is working.

Code :

```php
      if ($sidx == "contact.full_identite") {  
        $dons = $dons->with(['projet','contact'])
        ->join('projet','projet.ID_PROJET',"=",'don.ID_PROJET')
        ->join('contact','contact.ID_CONTACT',"=",'don.ID_CONTACT')
        ->select('don.*','contact.MAIL','contact.ADRESSE1','contact.CDPOST','contact.COMMUNE','contact.PAYS','contact.SOLLICITE','projet.LIBELLE_PROJ')
        ->get();
        if (strtoupper($sord) == "ASC") {
          $dons = $dons->sortBy(function($don) {
            return $don->contact->identite;
          });
        }
        if (strtoupper($sord) == "DESC") {
          $dons = $dons->sortByDesc(function($don) {
            return $don->contact->identite;
          });
        }
        $dons = $dons->splice($start,$limit);
      }
```